# Making a batch file do something once

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm making a game and I want a personalized username option that only appears once.

Here is an example:

```
@echo off
:onetime
echo please enter a username
echo.
set /p newuser=%newuser%:
echo %newuser%> cfg.txt
goto menu


:menu
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (cfg.txt) do echo %%x
cls
...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make :onetime happen once, so that it sends the username to cfg.txt

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up your code and provided a completed working script, and noted where you will put your game code.

Although Delayed expansion is not needed for this code, I have placed it in the script as you had it in your original script.

Please be mindful of the variable names I have chosen as they are used in several locations.

I have tried to comment the code with info on what it is doing, and I would be happen to explain further if needed.

I'd like to actually play your game when you are completed with it, if I may. :)

Hope that helps.

Ben

**BPG.cmd**

```
REM Script: BPG.cmd
REM Version: 1.0
REM Description:  Game to play about Monsters.
Rem Notes: Currently Implementing Menu System.

Rem Sets up Variables and checks if the script needs to be re-called.
@(
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDelayedExpansion
    echo off
    SET "eLvl=0"
    SET "ScriptFolder=%~dp0"
    SET "Log=%~dpn0.log"
    SET "ConfigFile=%~dpn0_cfg.txt"
    IF /I "%~1" NEQ "MAX" (
        ENDLOCAL
        ECHO.Game not started Maximized, Opening in a New Window by Running: Start "BPG 1 A Batch of Monsters" /MAX "%~dpnx0" MAX
        Start "BPG 1 A Batch of Monsters" /MAX "%~dpnx0" MAX
        EXIT /b %eLvl%
    )
    COLOR 2
)

REM Calls Main Function.
CALL :Main

REM Ends the script.
(
    ENDLOCAL
    EXIT /b %eLvl%
)

REM Main Function, most of your coding goes here, and this function calls sub functions.
:Main


    Rem Check if Config file exists, if it does not, then call the New User Function.
    IF NOT EXIST "%ConfigFile%" (
        CALL :NewUser
    )

    Rem Load Username from Config file.
    FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('Type "%ConfigFile%"') DO (
        SET "_UserName=%%~A"
    )

    Rem Call Menu System
    CALL :Menu

    REM Based off the option chosen Either Start a new Game or Skip to the End.
    REM ECHO.CALL %_Menu_Choice%
    CALL %_Menu_Choice%

GOTO :EOF

:NewUser
    SETLOCAL

    REM Get the Username Input
    SET /P "_User=Please Enter a Username: "

    REM Output the Username to the config file, overwriting all the file contents:
    echo.%_User%>"%ConfigFile%"

    ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF

:Menu

    SETLOCAL

    REM Output the Config file contents:
    Type "%ConfigFile%"

    REM Clear the screen
    cls  
    echo  ______   _______   _______ 
    echo I  ___ \ I  ____ I I ____  \
    echo I I   I II I    II I I    \/
    echo I I__/ / I I____II I I      
    echo I  __ I  I  _____I I I ____ 
    echo I I  \ \ I I       I I \_  I
    echo I I___I II I       I I___I I
    echo I______/ I_/       I_______I A BATCH OF MONSTERS
    echo.
    echo.
    echo 1) Begin
    echo.
    echo 2) Exit
    echo.
    set /p "_Choice=%_UserName%, Enter a Number: "

    (
        REM End the local variable Space, and Set return variables based on the choice, or re-draw the menu.
        ENDLOCAL
        IF /I "%_Choice%" EQU "1" (
            REM ECHO.%_Choice% EQU 1
            SET "_Menu_Choice=:Begin_Game"
        ) ELSE (
            IF /I "%_Choice%" EQU "2" (
                REM ECHO.%_Choice% EQU 2
                SET "_Menu_Choice=GOTO :EOF"
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO.%_Choice% Not Valid!
                PAUSE
                GOTO :Menu
            )
        )
    )
goto :EOF

:Begin_Game

    REM All the remaining code for your game should probably go here.

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for that man, I'll experiment with it and give it a go, also I'd love for you to play it when it's done :D

Comment: Hello Yoshirou, Sounds good.  I look forward to hearing back.  Please note, I'm not sure why you have in your script the output of the contents of the config file just prior to the menu clearing the screen.  I left this in place but you'll never see the output as the next command clears the screen.

Comment: Thanks so much man, and I probably just forgot to delete it at some point, I tried the script a minute ago and it works perfect, I cant wait to complete the game and that was a big help, really appreciated

Comment: Thanks, glad to help!  Please vote my answer up since it was helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help a while back, I got around to finishing the game! I thought I might as well link you it https://www.dropbox.com/s/41ddehle05gq3pp/bpg1.0.exe?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

try checking file existence :

```
@echo off
:onetime
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "cfg.txt" (
 echo please enter a username
 echo.
 set /p newuser=%newuser%:
 echo !newuser!> cfg.txt
 goto menu
)


:menu
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (cfg.txt) do echo %%x
cls
```

Comment: Thanks il give it a go!

Comment: Actually it just output "echo is off"

Comment: @Yoshirou - It works perfectly. Sounds like you hit enter without entering anything.

Comment: I can guarantee that that's not the case, here is the original code

Comment: `@echo off`
`if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b`
`title BPG 1 A batch of monsters `
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
`color 2`
`:username`
`if not exist "cfg.txt" (`
`echo Please enter a username`
`echo.`
`set /p c=%newuser%:`
`echo %c%> cfg.txt`
`goto menu`
`)`

Comment: `:menu`
`for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (cfg.txt) do echo %%x`
`cls  `
`echo  ______   _______   _______ `
`echo I  ___ \ I  ____ I I ____  \`
`echo I I   I II I    II I I    \/`
`echo I I__/ / I I____II I I   `   
`echo I  __ I  I  _____I I I ____ `
`echo I I  \ \ I I       I I \_  I`
`echo I I___I II I       I I___I I`
`echo I______/ I_/       I_______I A BATCH OF MONSTERS`
`echo.`
`echo.`
`echo 1) begin`
`echo.`
`echo 2) exit`
`echo.`
`set /p c=%newuser%:`

`if "%c%" == "1" goto new`
`if "%c%" == "2" exit`
`goto menu`

Comment: @Yoshirou - Use `echo !c!>cfg.txt` instead of `echo %c%>cfg.txt`. Use the code that was provided to you that actually works instead of trying to make it your own.

Comment: @SomethingDark That would probably cause me less problems but where's the fun in that :D thanks man